# Bind variable to ItemRender component property

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flash-builder, itemrenderer

I would like to bind a variable from my ActionScript to a property of a component that is in a ItemRender. But I always get this error:

> 1120: Access of undefined property
>   currentRoom.

Here is my code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:Canvas xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml" xmlns:solutionItems="com.barco.components.ControlRoomConfigurator.solutionItems.*">
    <mx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import com.barco.VO.ControlRoomConfigurator.Room;

            [Bindable] private var myArrayCollection:ArrayCollection;
            [Bindable] public var currentRoom:Room;


        ]]>
    </mx:Script>
    <mx:List id="listVideoWalls" 
         borderThickness="0"
         dataProvider="{myArrayCollection}" >
        <mx:itemRenderer>
            <mx:Component>
                <solutionItems:displaySolutionItem solutionId="{data.meetsRequirements.getItemAt(currentRoom.id)}" />
            </mx:Component>
        </mx:itemRenderer>
    </mx:List>
</mx:Canvas>
```

I would like to use the object currentRoom in my ItemRenderer component.
How do you do this?

I hope you understand my question.

Thanks!

Vincent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One short solution  is using **outerDocument** as

```
solutionId="{data.meetsRequirements.getItemAt(outerDocument.currentRoom.id)}"
```

for details read [Understanding Flex itemRenderers](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/articles/itemrenderers_pt1.html)

Hopes that helps

Comment: -1.  Very bad practice as now you're assuming that the outerDocument will always have that property.

Comment: i wrote its short solution :)

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that `<mx:Component>` definition declares a new scope. So it can't access current mxml file scope directly. `<mx:Component>` is just a shortcut for prototyping purposes to have a quick draft. But from the scope point of view it is the same as if you extract your component in a separate file. So extract it and stop be confusing :)